# Is the Visual Studio Code Extension Generator broken?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yeoman-generator

I'm following the instructions to build a "hello world" extension for Visual Studio as outlined [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world). I've got the Yeoman generator installed, but it seems buggy. For one thing, unless I immediately select one of the initial options when generating a new extension, I'm unable to select an option. Further, if I do immediately select an option (i.e. before enter stops working), I'm prompted to give a name to the extension. However, no matter how furiously I pound on my keyboard, no characters shows seem to be registered by the generator application.

Has anyone else experienced these issues with the generator? I'd really like to start experimenting with VS Code extensions, but if the generator doesn't work I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I also suffered from these issues but I couldn't figure out why.  
on my friend's computer, the yeoman ran ok so I just asked him to send me the generated folder.

Comment: I also had these problems on Windows. I found that it worked properly if I used Git Bash or Powershell instead of cmd.exe to run yeoman

Answer (score 0):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/485) with `yo` in node 7.1.0. You have to upgrade or downgrade node.js.